# Jquery selector for not <strong> text

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have the following HTML code:

```
<span class="c">
     <div class="a">
          <strong>Occupation</strong> Programmer
     </div>
</span>
```

How can I only select the word Programmer from the div tag, using jquery selectors?

I've tried using:

```
     $("div.a:not(strong)")

     $("span > div.a:not(strong)")
```

among others to no avail.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Selectors cannot select a text node. Can't you wrap the text `Programmer` inside a span or something?

Comment: Sadly, I can't wrap the word Programmer in another tag. I know I could select the word Occupation using $("div.a strong") and I'm curious to see if I could do something similar with the word Programmer.

Comment: Ok what is your end task. After selecting the text, what are you going to do with that?

Comment: jquery isnt designed to work on texnode/comment. You could use `contents()` method and filter it out regarding nodeType or nodeName and get DOM node `nodeValue` property. But simple way would be to use `$('div.a strong')[0].nextSibling.nodeValue.trim()`

Comment: As you both have commented, I had imagined it wasn't possible through the use of just jquery selectors. Thanks for the help and other possibilities though.

Comment: There is no selector in jQuery to select textNode, just like there isn't in plain CSS. You have to use relevant filtering/transversing methods. That's said as a side note, your HTML markup is invalid, a `span` shouldn't contain a block element as a `div`

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this- you are removing `strong` element from `#a`, and selecting other text

```js
var a = $("#a").clone().find('strong').remove().end().text().trim();

alert(a);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="c">
     <div id="a">
          <strong>Occupation</strong> Programmer
     </div>
</span>
```

Comment: That is very expensive way to select a textnode and not really readable imho

Comment: Thanks for the answer, though I was searching for a way that only used jquery selectors.